# Bootstrap: how do I make horizontal form's "inline-help" look better when it's too long?

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, css

I feel that the help line being so inconsistent is pretty ugly. Is there an easy way I can beautify it?

Here is a basic example of what I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/TyBwc/1/

```
<form class="form form-horizontal">
    <div class='control-group'>
        <label class='control-label' for='inputWarning'>Input with warning</label>
        <div class='controls'>
            <input id='inputWarning' type='text'>
            <span class='help-inline'>Something  afdaf da</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='control-group'>
        <label class='control-label' for='inputWarning'>Input with warning</label>
        <div class='controls'>
            <input id='inputWarning' type='text'>
            <span class='help-inline'>Something  afdaf da Something  afdaf da Something  afdaf da Something  afdaf da Something  afdaf da Something  afdaf da </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

As you can see, when help text is short, it looks nice, but when it overflows, it goes down to the bottom, giving it an inconsistent look.

How would I go about forcing the long help text to stay to the right of the form, using a sort of 3-column layout? Or possibly create a larger top-margin if does overflow to the bottom? And preferably, I'd like to keep it all responsive, so that smaller screens won't be impacted negatively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the trick.

```
.hil {
    width:200px;   
}

<span class='help-inline hil'> Long Text </span>
```

See images below

[image: Desktop Layout]

[image: Responsive Layout]

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/TyBwc/2/ It's still not consistent. Maybe just won't use the default bootstrap controls and just use row-fluid + span2, span7, and span3, respectively, to keep them all side by side.

Comment: Would you mind adding the .hil class to the help-inline class. See this fiddle. The solution I proposed is just easier for you, try it. It works: http://jsfiddle.net/TyBwc/3/ and don't forget to reward me with points :)

Comment: Ah yes, I missed that. Is there any way to make it responsive, so that it's not specifically tied to 200px, but make it adjust according to the browser width? Bigger screens should be able to have wider help lines.

Comment: Thanks. Don't forget to upvote me. It helps me increase my points here. I would be thankful. Moreover, it is responsive at this stage, please see the images I've attached. And yes, you can always make it responsive using CSS3 Media Queries :)

Comment: I've accepted your answer. What I meant, is that I'd rather it used percentage widths, instead of pixels. That way, they can grow with the size of the browser. Any ideas? Similar to how span3, span8, etc works in bootstrap.

Comment: I will get back to you with another fiddle in a while. Stay tuned. Going to sleep for a while. :)

Comment: Got any suggestions on this, by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

You could use media queries to display them below the text inputs on small screens:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .help-inline {
    display: block;
    float: none;
  }
}
```